# How do I smooth this cone for 3D printing?

Tags: 3d-printing, smooth

I have a cone that I'm setting up to 3D print:

[image]

When I import it into Cura, it's very blocky:

[image]

How can I edit this cone in Blender to give it a nice, smooth, round shape, while leaving the bottom perfectly flat and the cube inset intact?

Comment: Pro-tip: whenever I'm modeling for 3D printing I keep the shading set to *Shade Flat*, that way the smoothness you're seeing in the viewport is always what you get in the print.

Answer (score 1):

Try a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> > *Smooth Vertices* and play with the parameters in the Operator box:

[image]

Before and after:

[image]

Comment: Even better use a Smooth Modifier and keep it non-destructive.

Comment: Sure you can but it looks like he wants to 3D print  ;)

Comment: Well, yeah, but then you just set *Apply Modifiers* when exporting the file.

Comment: Moonbots, do I need to convert the triangles to quads first?  I've tried what you're showing, and it doesn't seem to affect my mesh above, or even a new cone added to the scene.

Comment: Yes I've tried with triangles and it's far from perfect, maybe try an Alt J (Tris to Quads), also don't forget to tweak the parameters in the Operator box